# Poppler.h fatal error while installing Slider from git on Tanglu (Debian)

Tags: debian, make

People!

Trying to install little PDF presentation soft (https://github.com/TrilbyWhite/Slider).

When trying to do "make" I get this:

```
slider.h:9:21: fatal error: poppler.h: No such file or directory
```

if I go to slider.h and change the `#include<poppler.h>` to `<#include </usr/include/poppler/glib/poppler.h>`, then I get:

```
/usr/include/poppler/glib/poppler.h:22:25: fatal error: glib-object.h: No such file or directory  #include <glib-object.h>
```

So maybe could someone help me with this. Is it just unsatisfied dependencies or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On wheezy I get

```
root@orwell:/home/faheem# apt-file search poppler.h
emscripten: /usr/share/emscripten/tests/poppler/glib/poppler.h
emscripten: /usr/share/emscripten/tests/poppler/glib/reference/html/poppler-poppler.html
emscripten-doc: /usr/share/emscripten/demos/poppler.html
libpoppler-glib-dev: /usr/include/poppler/glib/poppler.h
libpoppler-glib-dev: /usr/share/doc/libpoppler-glib-dev/html/poppler/poppler-poppler.html
libpoppler-glib-doc: /usr/share/gtk-doc/html/poppler/poppler-poppler.html
```

Do you have `libpoppler-glib-dev` or similar installed?

Also, did you really mean

```
<#include </usr/include/poppler/glib/poppler.h>
```

? I think you want something like

```
#include <poppler/glib/poppler.h>
```

Comment: Thank you for your trouble, resolved it by re-cloning the git and then everything worked flawlessly :)